# Template undefined reference on windows with MinGW 4.8

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, mingw, explicit-instantiation

I am using static template members in a class; the templates are instantiated in a cpp built in a software. I have a plug-in for the software that uses the  `name()` template method in the header, but does not build the source file which contains the instantiation. The build **works on Linux with g++-4.9** but fails on MinGW 4.8. I want to know how to make it work with the *almost* same compiler, but on Windows instead.

.hpp :

```
enum class ToplevelMenuElement
{
    FileMenu, 
    ...
    AboutMenu
};

enum class FileMenuElement
{
    New,
    ... ,
    Quit
};

// Others menus macros are defined

class MenuInterface
{
    public:
        template<typename MenuType>
        static QString name(MenuType elt);

    private:
        static const std::map<ToplevelMenuElement, QString> m_map;
        static const std::map<FileMenuElement, QString> m_fileMap;
};
```

.cpp :

```
template<>
QString MenuInterface::name(ToplevelMenuElement elt)
{
    return m_map.at(elt);
}

template<>
QString MenuInterface::name(FileMenuElement elt)
{
    return m_fileMap.at(elt);
}

const std::map<ToplevelMenuElement, QString> MenuInterface::m_map
{
    {ToplevelMenuElement::FileMenu, QObject::tr("File")},
    ...
    {ToplevelMenuElement::AboutMenu, QObject::tr("About")}
};

const std::map<FileMenuElement, QString> MenuInterface::m_fileMap
{
    {FileMenuElement::New, QObject::tr("New")},
    ..., 
    {FileMenuElement::Quit, QObject::tr("Quit")}
};
```

Error :

```
undefined reference to `QString MenuInterface::name<ToplevelMenuElement>(ToplevelMenuElement)'
```

Is there any flag to use to make some kind of lazy instantiation ? Or should I build the .cpp containing the template instantiation in my plug-in ?

Comment: It's not useful to write a template method if its content is different according to the parameter(s) type.

Comment: @P0W This doesn't look like a duplicate since his code contains explicit specializations in the cpp file.

Comment: @vincentp it makes an interface easier to read (there would be ten different overloads else...)

Comment: @0x499602D2 okay re-opened

Comment: @Jean-Michaël Celerier: I totally agree with you, but the interest of template programming is genericity^^

Comment: @Well it does not cost me anything to do this (except the problem with this particular compiler), so why not ?

Comment: Also other people will be able to add their own types (at compile time) easily in their plugins with this way.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are linking a source file that contains explicit specializations, you need to declare your explicit specializations before you define them. From §14.7.3/3:

> A declaration of a function template, class template, or variable template being explicitly specialized shall precede the declaration of the explicit specialization. [ Note: A declaration, but not a definition of the template is required. — end note ]

So you need to put these after your class in your header file:

```
template<>
QString MenuInterface::name(ToplevelMenuElement elt);

template<>
QString MenuInterface::name(FileMenuElement elt);
```

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Try adding an explicit instantiation in the source file (i.e `template QString MenuInterface::name(ToplevelMenuElement)`...)

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier No, just `template QString MenuInterface::...`. Do it for both sepcializations.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier Did it work? If it didn't then I don't know any way to fix it other than to try putting the definitions in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times...declaration and definitions for templates should be same file.

Comment: It works just fine on Linux with gcc-4.9 so I hoped it would be the same on MinGW...

Comment: Only general definitions.